# How to eat a big burger?

Tags: food

If you go to a nice restaurant and order a burger, chances are the ingredients are good quality, and the burger stack up much higher than I can open my mouth.

[image]

<sub>Image source: http://www.corvallisadvocate.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/big-burger.jpg</sub>

*How can I consume such burger?* Things I've tried:

1. **Open my mouth as much as I can**. My mouth is not big enough; this just gets juice onto my nose instead.
2. **Disassemble the burger, then consume the ingredients separately**. Doesn't feel like a burger this way.
3. **Cut the burger with a fork and knife**. The fork does not go to the bottom layer, as a result the ingredients move around a lot and I get a very uneven cut.

Comment: Compress it as much as u can, and try to eat it upside down, I feel this is the easiest way

Comment: Totally agree with @MarioGarcia. Although I don't eat it upside down I think that compressing the burger is the only way to eat it properly.

Comment: Take off the top bun and eat the rest of it. Most of the burger volume is just bread anyway.

Comment: @MarioGarcia I feel like hanging from the ceiling will only complicate matters further

Answer (score 3):

**How to eat a big burger?**

When in Cache Creek,BC I always stop in at [Hungry Herbies](https://www.zomato.com/cache-creek-bc/hungry-herbies-cache-creek/menu) and eat their enormous ***Monster Burgers***.

No matter which way you decide to eat your burger, you will end up losing something of the word etiquette. Nevertheless, this is what I find helpful when eating burgers that only the Flintstones can truly enjoy.

Before cutting the burger in half, I pierce burger with six (6) toothpicks as well as squish it to accommodate my mouth and then I cut the sandwich in half. Make sure that the tomatoes are well pierced or they will make a quick dash to freedom when eating your meal.

As I eat my hamburger, I remove the toothpicks when needed in order to enjoy my food. Occasionally I will have to remove a toothpick and place it in another spot in the hopes of not letting this monstrosity win and spilling onto the plate or even worse me.

Somewhat of a chore this burger is to eat, but in the end I usually do a fine job at not being messy.

I am not one to stand by protocol or etiquette and most people do not mind my eating the **Monster Burger** in this fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Squishing the burger will generally get you a long way. The bun is mostly air, and there is a lot of space between the different ingredients.

With the flat of your hand, press on the top of the burger. Then pick it up with both hands, maintaining pressure to keep it squished.

If this isn't enough, you can try (in this same configuration) taking a bite from the top half, then a bite from the bottom half. This way, you still get the burger "feel", without is going up your nose.

Answer (score 1):

- Squish the burger - I actually enjoy the texture of a denser sandwich more.
- Eat some of the ingredients inevitably coming out of the sides - In your picture, it seems like that burger has chips in it. I like to take some of those out and eat them individually; this also helps if I end up not liking them, I take them out before enjoying the rest of the burger.
- Take alternating bites from the front and back - When biting into a full burger from one side, ingredients invariably start to spill out of the opposite side. Eat from both sides to minimize spillage.

Answer (score 0):

I usually eat my burgers using fork and knife.
Sure thing, it's way easier to cut when a sort of wooden 'stick' (skewer?) is holding the burger together (some good places serve it this way).
But even if no 'stick' is provided, it's very possible to do a decent job at using fork and knife. Firstly, you don't necesserily need to go with the fork all the way through: you can gently go through the top layers and if the knife is good and sharp (preferably serrated) you can gently cut through the layers. Cut small pieces at a time. No squeezing, no using force, so pieces won't slide away and make a mess. Just gently cut lady-like portions. Works nicely for me.
Still, if the skewer or whatever the wooden stick is called is present, although you do things exactly the same way, it goes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

How I eat a large burger depends on who I'm with and where I am.

It depends.

- If I'm alone and not sitting in the restaurant (for take away/to go), I have my way with it taking bites at my own pace fitting my mood. Then, I mop up with extra serviettes/dinner napkins.
- If I'm with friends or relatives for an informal munch (for take away/to go), ditto.
- If I'm with new acquaintances or for business dining in the restaurant, I order something else such as a soup 'n salad (with a light clear dressing or none at all.)
- All other times, I use #3.

Bon Appetit!